# How to mock a class that implements multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

How to mock the following class:

```
UserRepository : GenericRepository<User>, IUserRepository


public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

I am using Moq, and I am confused how to handle multiple interfaces correctly.

Comment: Is there a relationship between `IUserRepository` and `IGenericRepository`?  Is it required that an object that implements `IUserRepository` also implement `IGenericRepository<User>`?

Comment: What does the production code you're trying to test look like?

Answer (score 122):

Take a look at https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

**Advanced Features**

```
// implementing multiple interfaces in mock
var foo = new Mock<IFoo>();
var disposableFoo = foo.As<IDisposable>();
// now IFoo mock also implements IDisposable :)
disposableFoo.Setup(df => df.Dispose());
```

Comment: Adding to the this answer, if you need to pass the mock to a method that take IFoo, you can also switch IFoo and IDisposable, ie: var disposableFoo = new Mock<IDisposable>(); var foo = disposableFoo.As<IFoo>();

Comment: Or create a new interface for the test: 
```public interface IDisposableFoo : IFoo, IDisposable```

Comment: What about with `Mock.Of<Foo>()`? Is there a solution for it or I gotta refactor?

Comment: @jeromej - can you please elaborate the question, ty.

Comment: @ShloEmi I was wondering if there was a version using the short-hand version of `Mock.Of<>` (which returns the object directly) but there isn't.

Comment: @jeromej - maybe this will help a bit?

    var disposableFoo = new Mock<IFoo>().As<IDisposable>();

Answer (score 30):

There is a mechanism built into Moq for dealing with multiple interfaces.

Say we have an interface **IFoo** and an implementation of the same **Foo**. We also have **ClientOne** that uses IFoo.

We then have an interface **IFooBar : IFoo**, an implementation **FooBar : Foo, IFooBar** and a **ClientTwo** that uses IFooBar.

When creating an end-to-end test for the system we have an **IFooBar**, **ClientOne** and **ClientTwo**.  The **As<>()** function allows us to use the **Mock<IFooBar>** as a **Mock<IFoo>**.

```
public interface IFoo {
    int Id { get; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo {
    public int Id {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}

public interface IFooBar : IFoo  {
    string Name { get; }
}

public class FooBar : Foo, IFooBar {
    public string Name {
        get { return "AName"; }
    }
}

public class ClientOne {
    private readonly IFoo foo;

    public ClientOne(IFoo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public string Details {
        get { return string.Format("Foo : {0}", foo.Id); }
    }

}

public class ClientTwo {
    private readonly IFooBar fooBar;

    public ClientTwo(IFooBar fooBar) {
        this.fooBar = fooBar;
    }

    public string Details {
        get { return string.Format("Foo : {0}, Bar : {1}", fooBar.Id, fooBar.Name); }
    }

}


[TestMethod]
public void TestUsingBothClients() {

    var fooBarMock = new Mock<IFooBar>();
    var fooMock = fooBarMock.As<IFoo>();

    fooBarMock.SetupGet(mk => mk.Id).Returns(1);
    fooBarMock.SetupGet(mk => mk.Name).Returns("AName");

    var clientOne = new ClientOne(fooMock.Object);
    var clientTwo = new ClientTwo(fooBarMock.Object);

    Assert.AreEqual("Foo : 1", clientOne.Details);
    Assert.AreEqual("Foo : 1, Bar : AName", clientTwo.Details);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, you want have a single mock instance of `UserRepository`, and for the purposes of a test, setup calls to methods from both the `IGenericRepository<TEntity>` interface and the `IUserRepository` interface.

You can implement multiple interfaces with a single mock instance like this:

```
var genericRepositoryMock = new Mock<IGenericRepository<User>>();
genericRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.CallGenericRepositoryMethod()).Returns(false);

var userRepositoryMock = genericRepositoryMock.As<IUserRepository>();
userRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.CallUserRepositoryMethod()).Returns(true);
```

However, as D Stanley pointed out, the need to do this is probably an indication that there is a flaw in your design.

Answer (score 1):

You can spare a bit with declaring a common interface just for testing, like:

```
interface IA { void Work(); }
interface IB { void Rest(); }

class AB: IA, IB
{
    public void Work() { ... }
    public void Rest() { ... }
}

interface IABTest : IA, IB
{}

class SomeTest
{
    public void DoTest()
    {
        var ab = new Mock<IABTest>();
        ab.Setup(m => m.Work());
        ab.Setup(m => m.Rest());
    }
}
```