# Mockk : Mock more than one interface at the same time

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I'm trying to mock some interfaces using Mockk.

At some point, I have to create a mock that implements 2 interfaces.

For instance, using Moq in C#, I can do [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28145338/1679537) :

```
// implementing multiple interfaces in mock
var foo = new Mock<IFoo>();
var disposableFoo = foo.As<IDisposable>();
// now IFoo mock also implements IDisposable :)
disposableFoo.Setup(df => df.Dispose());
```

Is there a way to do that with Mockk ?

If I try something like

```
val foo : IFoo = mockk()
every { (foo as AutoCloseable).close() } just Runs
```

I get the following error (which makes sense) :

```
com.example.IFoo$Subclass0 cannot be cast to java.lang.AutoCloseable
```

I saw in the documentation that I can specify additional interfaces with `spyk`, but I don't want to use an actual implementation here.

Is there a way to do that ? Is there another approach ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible with `moreInterfaces` parameter.

Example from documentation with `spyk`. Should work with `mockk` as well:

```
val spy = spyk(System.out, moreInterfaces = *arrayOf(Runnable::class))
```

Comment: Damn, how did I manage to not try this ?? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Been using mockk for a couple years now and did not know this existed until today. Better late than never I guess. Thanks!